# React working with similar components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 identical  react components, as I do so to work with them separately, their goal is to display data only from other sources

Comment: Is this a question or a statement?

Comment: Question of course)

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Please try and elaborate a bit, and include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: Might want to think about re-writing it slightly. I cant see what the question is

Comment: So i have component,can i use this in page 2 times,but with other content

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is you want to use a component with different content more than one place in a page.

If this is your question, yes, you can use as many as you want, like this

```
render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <TheComponent content={"1"} />
            <TheComponent content={"2"} />
            ...
        </div>
     );

 }
```